# My Production flutter website give this error how to i resolve

Tags: flutter

I use this comment for build

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html --release
```

Error i am getting:

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'buffer')
at main.dart.js:161825:17
at brf.a (main.dart.js:5161:62)
at brf.$2 (main.dart.js:51400:14)
at bqc.$1 (main.dart.js:51394:21)
at bjF.aXW (main.dart.js:52226:34)
at bjF.DL (main.dart.js:52228:21)
at b5X.$0 (main.dart.js:51786:11)
at Object.GS (main.dart.js:5254:40)
at aX.w4 (main.dart.js:51708:3)
at b5P.$0 (main.dart.js:51754:13)
```

Comment: can you provide more details?